# Chat generates unlimited paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this part of code from a chat.js I am working on for my site and I want it to generate the chat in paragraphs but after 10 lines I want the first one to delete itself and so on so we can always watch the 10 last messages. How can I manage this?

Here is the part of the code that generates the `<p>`.

```
function updateChat(){
 if(!instanse){
     instanse = true;
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "process.php",
           data: {  
                    'function': 'update',
                    'state': state,
                    'file': file
                    },
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){
               if(data.text){
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                        $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
                    }                                 
               }
               document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
               instanse = false;
               state = data.state;
           },
        });
 }
 else {
     setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
 }}
```

Comment: `$('#chat-area>p:gt(10)').remove()`

Comment: do i add this inside the for ?

Comment: `$('#chat-area p').first().remove()`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol given that the new lines are appended, not prepended, won't that delete the new lines, so you only ever see the *first* ten?

Comment: nothing of this worked out just keep generating infinite lines and messes up my whole site

Comment: `#chat-area { max-height:240px; overflow:scroll; }`

Comment: @freedomn-m Maybe XD Didn't pay too much attention to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++){
    $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
    if($('#chat-area > p').length > 10){
        $('#chat-area > p').first().remove();
    }
}
```

or if you want to do just one check after the for:

```
if($('#chat-area > p').length > 10){
    $('#chat-area > p').slice(0, $('#chat-area > p').length - 10).remove();
}
```

Comment: sorry but it just continue to generate more lines

Comment: try the line inside the second IF in console and see what happens

Comment: $('#chat-area > p').remove(); -> is this doing something ?

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution would beto iterate the last 10 entries and append them to container. a helper function to take last 10 entries should be written like this.

```
>takeLast = function(ary, batch_size) {
...  return ary.slice(ary.length-batch_size, ary.length);
... }

>x = 
[ 'Lorem',
  'ipsum',
  'dolor',
  'sit',
  'amet,',
  'consectetuer',
  'adipiscing',
  'elit,',
  'sed',
  'diam',
  'nonummy',
  'nibh',
  'euismod',
  'tincidunt',
  'ut',
  'laoreet',
  'dolore',
  'magna',
  'aliquam',
  'erat',
  'volutpat.',
 ]

>take(x, 10)
[ 'nibh',
  'euismod',
  'tincidunt',
  'ut',
  'laoreet',
  'dolore',
  'magna',
  'aliquam',
  'erat',
  'volutpat' ]
```